# How to Update bios on Dell OptiPlex 780 with Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, bios

I got a used Dell OptiPlex 780 with no os;  I installed Ubuntu 21.10 on it.  I wanted to upgrade the processor, but you need the latest BIOS available;  I have to upgrade. The upgrade I am trying to do is from BIOS revision A-12 to A-15. There are tutorials for the process, but they all require you to have Windows installed.  There is an app for doing the bios update process on Ubuntu called `fwupdmgr`.  When I run `fwupdmgr update` I get this error.
`WARNING:UEFI firmware can not be updated in legacy BIOS mode See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:legacy-bios for more information.`
The dell OptiPex 780 only has legacy BIOS mode with the old BIOS.

Dell has a tutorial for this process on their website https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment  My dell model was made before 2015, so I did the pre-2015 tutorial, but it is outdated and does not work on ubuntu 21.10.

I tried running the bios.exe with wine, but it gave me this error[image]
I tried a reboot like it said, but it gave me the same error.

I DO have the right version of BIOS as I made sure the version I downloaded was the right one by searching for the bios with the product code found on the case of the pc.  The question is, how to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us

- pop in your dell serial number, or optiplex 780.
- drivers & downloads tab
- get the O780-A15.exe
- because optiplex pc from dell is/was a basic pc offering from dell, and is now outdated, does not surprise me they only offer a windows exe for bios update
- get WINE https://www.winehq.org/ and *hope* the windows exe bios update works through linux+wine
- option 2 : buy a $20 ssd or hdd off amazon/ebay for temporary use, download windows10.iso from microsoft and install and then run O780-A15.exe; you don't need to activate or pay for windows for a 5 minute bios update

  - if your optiplex780 does not support win10, then look at getting windows7.

Comment: I tried it wit wine (I forgot to add that)

Comment: if it didn't work with WINE, no surprise being a bios update, then i think for the optiplex you're going to need to go the install windows on a separate disk to run the dell bios update exe.  The more current dell products, servers especially offer a .BIN file that runs in linux that does do bios update as well as firmware updates.  But my experience is for the cheaper/older stuff like you have support is limited and your stuck with the windows based exe update for the bios

Comment: i use optiplex 780 as a doorstop  :)

Comment: and being dell, you may be able to email dell support and ask for a Dell restore CD/DVD that has... probably windows7, that can be installed and licensed to run windows.  I used to use the black dell windows restore cd and reinstall windows 7 all the time back in the day.  Might have to pay $10 shipping but that would get you a working licensed legit copy of windows, albeit win7.  Or look for a windows7.iso download somewhere- you don't need to license/activate windows to do just the bios update.

Comment: I successfully installed windows 10 on it without a license and updated it with that.   As for using it as a doorstop, I upgraded it so it wayyy outperforms newer, more expensive computers.  (I only paid $90 bucks for it and the upgrades) I as for gaming quality, when I play online video games, I am one of the few people who does not have bad fps and lag.

Comment: glad it worked out... i was teasing about the 780==doorstop, they were ok pc's back in their day.